# How to Change the Name of a Windows Phone 8 Project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, namespaces, visual-studio-2013

I have just run into an issue with my app name already being reserved in the Store. I have chosen another similar app name to reserve, but now I need to change my actual application solution name to match. I want to be sure that the name I chose in the store matches the name of the solution that a user will see on his or her device once downloaded and installed. How can I properly accomplish this? My previous experience has always resulted in many errors by simply changing the solution name within the solution explorer. Please help.

Comment: You don't need to change the solution name.  You can set the app name that shows on the phones menu in the WmAppManifest.

Comment: Thanks I was worried not changing the namespace or project solution name would somehow cause errors as well. Also would be good to note to change the app name anywhere in the project as well such as App.xaml if using a string resource elsewhere.